# R code debugging: named value in a loop not being created

Tags: r

I am using a chunk of code written by another person, found [here](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/452032_a5df2d3f782444fc830d43548a304ec5.html#PartA). There are two parts, with the second depending on a named value called `lyVCI` being created in the first part. The original code for the first part is:

```
if ((exists("AnalysisPeriod") && (sy > AnalysisPeriod[1] && sy < AnalysisPeriod[2])) || exists("AnalysisPeriod") == F){
  
   if (!(sy == max(as.numeric(YEARs)) && hemisphere == 0)){
    
    #Check for hemisphere, load VCI data for the season
    if (hemisphere == 1){
      lyVCI <- allVCI[grepl(sy,allVCI)]
      dscr <- sy
    }else{
      #Load correct data if southern hemisphere was selected (seasonality shift)
      lyVCI <- c(allVCI[grepl(sy,allVCI)],allVCI[grepl(sy+1,allVCI)])
      #Adjusting output filenames if southern hemisphere was selected
      if (sy == min(as.numeric(YEARs))){
        lyVCI <- lyVCI[1:23]
      }else{
        lyVCI <- lyVCI[13:35]
      }  
      #Adjusting output filenames if southern hemisphere was selected
      dscr <- paste0(sy,"_",sy+1)
    }
```

And the code for the second is:

```
yVCI <- stack(lyVCI)
```

I recognize that I need to add three more curly brackets to the end of the first chunk. As well, I have switched the hemispheres, since my data are in the north hemisphere instead of the south. However, when I run the code, this does not create the value `lyVCI`, and instead shows the following error message.

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :    error in evaluating the
> argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'stack': object
> 'lyVCI' not found

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no `lyVCI`. So, I assume that the condition of the statement was not true because `sy` was outside the analysis period. Or `sy` was the maximum of `YEARs` or `hemisphere` was not zero. You can print the values of `AnalysisPeriod`, `sy`, and all other variables to see which condition was False and what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @MartinWettstein Okay, I've done that! It looks like `sy` was outside the analysis period, as you said. I've tried changing the condition to `sy >= AnalysisPeriod[1] && sy <= AnalysisPeriod[2]`, but this now brings the error `Error in data.frame(values = unlist(unname(x)), ind, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 23, 0 `

Comment: Without knowing your data, I can't know what exactly is wrong. I'd guess that your data types are not the same as the ones from where you copy&pasted the code.